# Spin CCSprite Cocos2D?

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am trying to spin a CCSprite in Cocos2D but it is hard to explain in words so here is a GIF of the animation I am trying to achieve: http://max.wilsonsd.org:8080/Clip_Art/Pmpa3/symbols/miscellaneous/peace_sign_spinning_hw.gif

Anyway it is a 360 degree spin but not in a clockwise or counter-clockwise way. Anyway how would I achieve this in Cocos2D?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That effect is called flip, try with the CCFlipX/CCFlipX3D actions. For example

```
[sprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCFlipX3D actionWithDuration:1.0]]]
```

Good luck!

Comment: You may have to change CCDirector projection to 3D in cocos2d 2.0. It defaults to 2D projection which means some or all 3D actions don't display correctly.